# Doing operation on types where source and destination reference could be the same

Tags: rust

Below I have a function that could work on the same data as `source` and `destination`, or different ones. If you pass no source, it should treat the destination as the source.

```
use core::ops::IndexMut;
use core::ops::Index;
use core::marker::PhantomData;

struct B<'a, T>{
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>
}

struct BMut<'a, T>{
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'a mut T>
}

impl<'a, T> Index<T> for B<'a, T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, t: T) -> &T {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Index<T> for BMut<'a, T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, t: T) -> &T {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IndexMut<T> for BMut<'a, T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, t: T) -> &mut T {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> From<BMut<'a, T>> for B<'a, T> {
    fn from(_e: BMut<'a, T>) -> Self {
        B{
            _phantom: PhantomData
        }
    }
}

trait A where Self: Sized {
    fn transform(source: Option<&B<Self>>, destination: &mut BMut<Self>);
}

impl A for u64 {
    fn transform(source: Option<&B<Self>>, destination: &mut BMut<Self>) {
        let source = match source{
            Some(source) => source,
            None => destination.into()
        };
        //do a transformation here that reads and writes from destination.
        //In case we specified a source, then it uses it, otherwise uses destination
        //as a source. Technically this should be possible because it's impossible to pass 
        //a source that is equal to destination
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15a2cae5c1240890e6f611d79e74958f

The problem is that I cannot convert `BMut` to `B`. Yes, I could access `BMut` in the function `a` everytime I needed `B` if the source was not specified, but would be much cooler to have one type for source and be able to set it as destination only once.

⣿

Standard Error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&B<'_, u64>: From<&mut BMut<'_, u64>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:49:33
   |
49 |             None => destination.into()
   |                                 ^^^^ the trait `From<&mut BMut<'_, u64>>` is not implemented for `&B<'_, u64>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <B<'a, T> as From<BMut<'a, T>>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<&B<'_, u64>>` for `&mut BMut<'_, u64>`
```

Comment: BTW, `trait A where Self: Sized` can be shorten to `trait A: Sized`. Just noting ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think there's multiple issues here. The surface issue right now, from the compiler error, is that the conversion doesn't work, right? And the compiler tells you why. It knows how to turn an *owned* `BMut` into an *owned* `B` but it doesn't know how to do that for references.

Now in your playground example you're using phantom data, but I assume that in reality your structs contain (and own!) actual pieces of interesting data that doesn't implement the `Copy` trait.

The problem then is that, to *cheaply* create a `B` out of a `BMut` you need to move those owned values into the new struct. That's what `From` and `Into` do, anyway. But you can't move things out of a shared reference.

Another issue: The borrow checker doesn't actually let you write a function that takes two separate mutable references as arguments which you then call with the same data. What I mean is:

```rust
fn some_operation(&mut source: SomeType, &mut dest: SomeType) {
  dest.do_something_mutable(source.get_some_info())
}

fn main() {
  let source_and_dest = SomeType::new();
  
  some_operation(&mut source_and_dest, &mut source_and_dest); // ERROR!
}
```

The compiler will complain because now you're taking two mutable references of the same variable, which the borrow checker doesn't like.

So maybe that's what you mean when you say "If you pass no source, it should treat the destination as the source"? But still, you can't then take the destination and obtain a mutable reference from it that'll let you treat it as a source. You really have to write two pieces of logic, one for when source and destination are both given and different, and one where you're operating on the same data.

Maybe with a bit more context on what's behind the scenes of your code (your minimal reproducible example is *very* terse) we can help more specifically.

Comment: yes, you're right. What I wanted was to be able to do the FFT on something that implements `Index` for reading the coefficients (`B`) and `IndexMut` for something that writes the coefficients (`BMut`). Sometimes it's better to transform the array itself, but sometimes you want to store the transformation somewhere else. Remember that `B` has a constant reference to the coefficients to be transformed, and `BMut` has a mutable reference

Comment: The code that you shared doesn't show that. You're just using `PhantomData` in either case, and your `a` function takes `&mut` for both the `B` and `BMut` field.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to make the minimum example really big, because then I need to make sure that T can be used to index and also implement SliceIndex, etc. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: of course this could be solved with a macro, os some `if` that picks from the source or destination depending if source is available. However, doing the source check every time would be costly, so I need a way to point to the right source. Of course, without `unsafe`.

Comment: Yeah but the minimum example doesn't contain important information about what's actually contained in the structs. Make it as simple as possible, but not simpler :) And the issue with having two references to the same struct, one of the references being mutable, won't go away that way either.

Comment: @MargarethReena for example, you say that "`T` can be used to index and also implement `SliceIndex`, etc" but this is actually irrelevant to your question. For the sake of the question, you could get rid of `T` and write e.g. `struct B<'a> { buffer: &'a[f32], }`

Comment: @Jmb yes I agree, sorry. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @Jmb and @Lagerbaer take a look, I made a more detailed self-explanatory example with `Index` and `IndexMut`. But basically I want to either transform a mutable indexable object, or transform from the non-mutable to the mutable one. By transformation I mean, for example, adding +1 to all coefficients of a slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a macro if `BMut` implements `DerefMut<Target=Self>` and `B` implements `Deref<Target=Self>` / `BMut`'s fields and functions are a superset of `B`'s. No extra checks required.

```rust
impl A for u64 {
    fn transform(source: Option<&B<Self>>, destination: &mut BMut<Self>) {
        match source{
            Some(source) => transformation!(source, destionation),
            None => transformation!(destination, destination),
        }
    }
}
```